# What is the "binary:logistic" objective function in XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, boosting

I am reading through Chen's [XGBoost](http://www.kdd.org/kdd2016/papers/files/rfp0697-chenAemb.pdf) paper. He writes that during the $\text{t}^{\text{th}}$ iteration, the objective function below is minimised.

$$ L^{(t)} =  \sum_{i}^n l(y_i, \hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i)) + \Omega (f_t)$$

Here, $l$ is a differentiable convex loss function, $f_t$ represents the $\text{t}^{\text{th}}$ tree and $\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)}$ represents the prediction of the $\text{i}^{\text{th}}$ instance at iteration $t-1$.

I was wondering what $l$ is when using XGBoost for binary classification?

Comment: $l$ is the log likelihood of the bernoulli distribution.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewDrury. So should I think of $\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i)$ as the $p$ parameter of a bernoulli distribution? It feels like $\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i)$ ought to be passed through the logistic function to get a probability?

Comment: That's correct.  The expression you cite takes the role of the linear predictor in logistic regression.

Comment: So should I think of $\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i)$ as a probability, or $\text{logistic}(\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i))$ as the probability?

Comment: The second one, the first one is a log-odds.

Comment: So $l = y_i \log(\text{logistic}(\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i))) + (1-y_i)\log(1-\text{logistic}(\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i)))$

Comment: Yup.  You usually rewrite that in a slightly different, but algebraically equivelent, way, as $l = y_i (\hat y_i^{t-1} + f_t(x_i)) - \log(1 + \exp (\hat y_i^{t-1} + f_t(x_i)))$

Comment: No problem.  I'll try to write this up in an answer tonight so people don't have to dig through the comments to follow the discussion.

Answer (score 8):

It appears there is an option objective: "binary:logistic"

> “binary:logistic” –logistic regression for binary classification,
> output probability
>
> “binary:logitraw” –logistic regression for binary
> classification, output score before logistic transformation

See http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html

(so log loss)

Answer (score 3):

I'm just summarizing the comments under the problem description:

$l$ is the log likelihood of the bernoulli distribution, where 
$\text{logistic}(\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i))$ is the probability.
So the formula should be
$$l = y_i \log(\text{logistic}(\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i))) + (1-y_i)\log(1-\text{logistic}(\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(x_i)))$$

or algebraically equivelent,
$$l = y_i (\hat y_i^{t-1} + f_t(x_i)) - \log(1 + \exp (\hat y_i^{t-1} + f_t(x_i)))$$
using the property that $\sigma(-z)=1 - \sigma(z)$.